# Регулярное выражение получение подстроки из ссылки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть ссылка "https://github.com/facebook/react". Нужно достать слова, которые будут стоять на местах, где сейчас находяться facebook и react, можно сделать отдельными выражениями, результат должен просто отдавать 2 слова или по 1, если будет 2 регулярных выражения.  Длина слов можем менятся, но шаблон статичен

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZVbyLz/1, `([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$` попробуйте так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var s = "https://github.com/facebook/react"
var [, x, y] = s.match(/^https:\/\/github.com\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)$/)
console.log(x, y)
```